# Qt 4.8.2. Элемент-список изменения размера шрифта

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Я делаю простой текстовый редактор по примеру из методички. Мне нужно иметь возможность сделать текст разного размера 14-12 пт и так далее, а также изменять сам шрифт Times New Roman, Arial и так далее. Какие элементы для этого можно использовать? Остальной функционал вроде бы реализовал. Прикрепляю к вопросу скриншот готового приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: `QFont` пригодится, полагаю. [ссылка](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html)

Comment: Ну а если под элементами Вы имели в виду элементы управления - то справа есть `QComboBox`, `QCheckBox`, `QSpinBox`, а слева элемент для редактирования текста, не помню как он называется, `QTextEdit` наверное. У его свойства `textDocument` как раз и свойство `defaultFont` есть

Comment: Ну и сама панель справа - видимо `QGroupBox` - у неё и рамка и есть и `title` (параметры на скриншоте)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html посмотрите тут, этот пример более масшабный, но если разберетесь будет гуд

Answer (score 0):

Я бы повесил на сигнал `valueChanged()` (сигналы могут по разному называться, это просто пример) элементов `fontComboBox`, `sizeSpinBox` и чекбоксы курсива, полужирного и подчеркнутого один слот, который перечитывает текущие значения и устанавливает новый шрифт для `QTextEdit`. Выглядит примерно так:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QObject *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(ui);

    connect(ui->fontComboBox, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, this, &MainWindow::updateFont);
    connect(ui->italicCheckBox, &QComboBox::stateChanged, this, &MainWindow::updateFont);
    // соединяем остальные
}

void MainWindow::updateFont()
{
    QFont currentFont = ui->textEdit->currentFont();

    currentFont->setFamily(ui->fontComboBox->currentText());
    currentFont->setItalic(ui->italicCheckBox->isChecked());
    currentFont->setPointSize(ui->sizeSpinBox->value());

    // устанавливаем остальные свойства

    textEdit->setCurrentFont(currentFont);
}
```

Либо, как вариант, можно повесить на каждый элемент формы, отвечающий за изменение шрифта, по своему слоту, например так:

```
void MainWindow::updateItalic()
{
    QFont font = ui->textEdit->currentFont();
    font->setItalic(ui->italicCheckBox->isChecked());

    ui->textEdit->setCurrentFont(font);
}

// аналогично для семейства, размера и других чекбоксов
```

Но в этом случае встает вопрос о целесообразности создания кучи слотов, если кол-во обрабатываемых элементов на форме будет увеличиваться.

Answer (score 0):

Как задать конкретный кегль я не знаю, а шрифт - есть у меня comboBox со списком шрифтов, шрифт я задаю как

`ui->textEdit->setFont(QFont(comboBox->currentText(), 12, ui->textEdit->font().bold(), ui->textEdit->font().italic()));`

Заполняю комбо бокс вот так:

`QStringList sl = QFontDatabase().families();
 comboBox->addItems(sl);`